# is there a way to change the textview text in the MainActivity whenever the text in recyclerview row changed in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

I an trying to do a simple app, in which I use `RecyclerView`.
Here are  my files.

```
MainActivity.kt
```

`activity_main.xml`  --> which has `RecyclerView` (recylerViewMain)
`single_row.xml` --> single row for recyclerViewMain

`MainAdapter.kt` --> where all bindings , `ViewHolder` and inflating

I have also 
`Product.kt`  --> model for Products

Now, here what i am trying to do.

I have added Plus and Minus buttons on the side of itemUnit and whenever i click those items it does the job i wanted, increasing the itemUnit and eventually, itemAmount

However, this happens only on Row, and it doesn't change the Sub Total (`TextView`) in `main_activity.xml` file.

Is there a way to change the `main_activity` `textView` whenever `textView` in the Row of `Recyclerview` changes (or whenever button clicked on the row) ?

I am editing the code here.
`Sub Total` amount doesn't change until I click an item button (Granola, Brownie etc.). Only after I click the these items `Sub Total`  changes and gives the updated amount.

the interface solution didnt work for me, I think I couldnt implement it right.

here are the codes ;

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ItemChangeListener {
override var subTotalAmnt: Double = 30.0
//override var subTotalAmount: Double = 50.0

//override fun onItemPriceChange(20.0)

lateinit var mRecyclerView : RecyclerView
private lateinit var sDatabase: DatabaseReference
var trId: Long = 0

var discAmnt : Double = 0.00

var unt = 1

var tr :Trans ?= null

var sb = 0.00
var disc = sb*.1
var tt = sb-disc

var list = ArrayList<Product>()


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)

    //var subto = findViewById(R.id.txtSubAmount) as TextView


   onItemPriceChange(20.0)
    txtSubAmount.text = subTotalAmnt.toString()

    sDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Sales")

    sDatabase.child("Sales").addValueEventListener(object:ValueEventListener{
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

        }

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            if(p0.exists()) {
                trId = p0.childrenCount
                println(trId)
            }
        }
    })
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_main)
    mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    mRecyclerView.adapter = MainAdapter(this, list)
```

and my Adapter Class;

```
class MainAdapter(val context: Context, val items : List<Product>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.PartViewHolder>() {
override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: MainAdapter.PartViewHolder, p1: Int) {
    p0.bindItems(items[p1])
}


 var itemListener: ItemChangeListener? = null
fun setListener(listener: ItemChangeListener) {
    this.itemListener = listener
}

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return super.getItemId(position)
}


override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return items.size
}

// Inflates the item views
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PartViewHolder {


    // LayoutInflater: takes ID from layout defined in XML.
    // Instantiates the layout XML into corresponding View objects.
    // Use context from main app -> also supplies theme layout values!
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    // Inflate XML. Last parameter: don't immediately attach new view to the parent view group
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sinlge_row, parent, false)

    return PartViewHolder(view)

}


// Binds each product in the ArrayList to a view


inner class PartViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {


    // Holds the TextView that will add each product to


    fun bindItems(prd: Product) {
        val textViewName = itemView.txtOrderNumber
        var textViewUnit = itemView.txtItemUnit
        val textViewPrice = itemView.txtItemPrice
        val textViewAmount = itemView.txtItemAmount


        var id = adapterPosition

        var unitN: Int = 1
        textViewName.text = prd.pName
        textViewUnit.text = prd.pUnit.toString()
        textViewPrice.text = prd.pPrice.toString()
        var itemPrice = prd.pPrice
        var itemAmount = itemPrice.times(unitN)
        textViewAmount.text = itemAmount.toString()

        itemView.btnPlus.setOnClickListener {

            println("item id : " + id)



            //itemListener = ItemChangeListener
            itemListener?.onItemPriceChange(10.0)

            // increase the Product model single unit
            prd.pUnit = unitN++

            // println("Here is the " +MainActivity().list.get(id))

            // bind txtItemUnit from single_row to changed unitN (single unit)
            textViewUnit.text = unitN.toString()

            // change the Product model single pAmount
            prd.pAmount = prd.pPrice.times(unitN)

            // bind txtItemAmount from single_row to Product pAmount
            textViewAmount.text = prd.pAmount.toString()

            //txtSubAmount.txt =

            //MainActivity().doSomething(subTotalAmount)


        }

        itemView.btnMinus.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {

            if (unitN >= 1) {
                prd.pUnit = unitN--
                println(prd.pUnit)
                textViewUnit.text = unitN.toString()

                textViewAmount.text = prd.pPrice.times(unitN).toString()
            } else
                prd.pUnit = 1
            textViewUnit.text = prd.pUnit.toString()
            textViewAmount.text = prd.pPrice.times(prd.pUnit).toString()
        })


    }


}
}
```

and, Interface

```
interface ItemChangeListener {

var subTotalAmnt : Double

fun onItemPriceChange(subTotalAmount : Double){

    this.subTotalAmnt = subTotalAmount
    println("onItemPriceChange "+subTotalAmnt)

}
}
```

I am sorry for this terrible explanation as I am not native, but willing to explain more for help.
[image: after clicking plus and increasing the unit]
Kind Regards.

Edited MainAdapter

```
class MainAdapter(val context: Context, val items : List<Product>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.PartViewHolder>() {
override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: MainAdapter.PartViewHolder, p1: Int) {
    p0.bindItems(items[p1])
}


lateinit var itemListener: ItemChangeListener
fun setListener(listener: ItemChangeListener) {
    this.itemListener = listener
}

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return super.getItemId(position)
}


override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return items.size
}

// Inflates the item views
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PartViewHolder {


    // LayoutInflater: takes ID from layout defined in XML.
    // Instantiates the layout XML into corresponding View objects.
    // Use context from main app -> also supplies theme layout values!
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    // Inflate XML. Last parameter: don't immediately attach new view to the parent view group
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sinlge_row, parent, false)

    return PartViewHolder(view)

}


// Binds each product in the ArrayList to a view


inner class PartViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {


    // Holds the TextView that will add each product to


    fun bindItems(prd: Product) {
        val textViewName = itemView.txtOrderNumber
        var textViewUnit = itemView.txtItemUnit
        val textViewPrice = itemView.txtItemPrice
        val textViewAmount = itemView.txtItemAmount


        var id = adapterPosition

        var unitN: Int = 1
        textViewName.text = prd.pName
        textViewUnit.text = prd.pUnit.toString()
        textViewPrice.text = prd.pPrice.toString()
        var itemPrice = prd.pPrice
        var itemAmount = itemPrice.times(unitN)
        textViewAmount.text = itemAmount.toString()

        itemView.btnPlus.setOnClickListener {

            println("item id : " + id)


            //itemListener = ItemChangeListener
            itemListener.onItemPriceChange(20.0)
            // increase the Product model single unit
            prd.pUnit = unitN++

            // println("Here is the " +MainActivity().list.get(id))

            // bind txtItemUnit from single_row to changed unitN (single unit)
            textViewUnit.text = unitN.toString()

            // change the Product model single pAmount
            prd.pAmount = prd.pPrice.times(unitN)

            // bind txtItemAmount from single_row to Product pAmount
            textViewAmount.text = prd.pAmount.toString()

            //txtSubAmount.txt =

            //MainActivity().doSomething(subTotalAmount)


        }

        itemView.btnMinus.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {

            if (unitN >= 1) {
                prd.pUnit = unitN--
                println(prd.pUnit)
                textViewUnit.text = unitN.toString()

                textViewAmount.text = prd.pPrice.times(unitN).toString()
            } else
                prd.pUnit = 1
            textViewUnit.text = prd.pUnit.toString()
            textViewAmount.text = prd.pPrice.times(prd.pUnit).toString()
        })


    }


}
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it using **interface**.

- First you create interface definition (in a separate file or in adapter).
  -- for eg: **interface ItemChangeListener { fun onItemPriceChange(pass itemprice or totalprice) }**
- next you create an object of listener inside adapter
- Like **lateinit var listener: ItemChangeListener** inside adapter (set using **fun setListener(listener:ItemChangeListener){ // code }** ).
- Let the main activity implement the interface.
- pass the mainActivity **this** to the **adapter.setListener**
- on Clicking the button, you can call listener.onItemPriceChange(pass itemprice or totalprice)
- you can get the parameter on main activity in this way.

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54222687/3192693) for some details.. Same can be done using constructor parameter I guess.

Comment: Not sure why you need to "create an object of listener inside adapter"... isn't that the Activity?

Comment: @AjahnCharles : Its for calling the onItemPriceChange() call back function. The interface should be implemented in MainActivity.

Comment: Do you mean a constructor parameter and field? Also this question is for Kotlin not Java.

Comment: @AjahnCharles : Oops, thanks for notifying. I was focused on the problem. It can be a constructor parameter or lateinit var I guess. I've updated the answer and the link.

Comment: I will try and see the resutl, thanks @MonsterBrain and AjahnCharles

Comment: thanks @MonsterBrain, I am trying it now, but when i put write `setListener(listener:ItemChangeListener){ // code  }` this part it gives me error. I am writing it in my Adapter. Also, any suggestion for the `//code` part for this function?

Comment: please elaborate on what error is occurring ? // code part will be like, `this.itemListener = listener` where itemListener is the property of adapter, like `lateinit var itemListener:ItemChangeListener`

Comment: Hi @MonsterBrain, i really appreciate your help. Error is gone after editing. But now giving new error. I have to edit the post and you can see the error there as well. Can you please check  edited **MainAdapter** class and error. Thanks

Comment: sorry. Please use `var itemListener:ItemChangeListener? = null` and check please

Comment: Thanks @MonsterBrain error is goen after using **?**, and I have to do the same for the code inside viewholder. But, here again, whenever I click  btnPlus still doesnt change the value in Interface or run the Interface function. I have edited question again, please check there

Comment: finally, managed to make it working. Thanks a million times. I find an answer for this question in another post. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56405975/change-textview-in-mainactvity-from-recycleradapter-using-kotlin?rq=1) that really works. Now, I am going to dig in more for seing my weak sides.